# How to remove rows by multiple values from checklist R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset checklist like this, or it can be called as remove list

```
ID   Place 
1       A   
2       B    
3       C   
4       D    
5       E  
6       E
```

And here is dataframe 1

```
ID   Place
1     A
1     B
1     C
1     D
1     H
1     J
2     A
2     B
2     F
2     J
2     D
3     A
3     E
3     C
3     T
4     D
4     E
5     A
5     E
5     U
6     A
6     B
6     C
6     E
6     F
```

I want to use 'ID Place' combination from the checklist to remove some rows in the dataframe 1 and the result should be like this

```
ID  Place
1   B
1   C
1   D
1   H
1   J
2   A
2   F
2   J
2   D
3   A
3   E
3   T
4   E
5   A
5   U
6   A
6   B
6   C
6   F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could do this with a `merge` in a few steps, you can bind the `remove` set to the original set of data, and then remove the added rows and any `duplicated` cases:

```
df1[tail(!duplicated(rbind(remove,df1)), -nrow(remove) ),]
#   ID Place
#2   1     B
#3   1     C
#4   1     D
#5   1     H
#6   1     J
#7   2     A
#9   2     F
#10  2     J
#11  2     D
#12  3     A
#13  3     E
#15  3     T
#17  4     E
#18  5     A
#20  5     U
#21  6     A
#22  6     B
#23  6     C
#25  6     F
```

Here's the merge code in 2 steps:

```
out <- merge(df1, transform(remove, drop=1), all=TRUE)
out[ is.na(out$drop), -match("drop", names(out)) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

```
dplyr::setdiff(df2, df1)
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors = F, text="ID   Place 
1       A   
2       B    
3       C   
4       D    
5       E  
6       E")  
df2 <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors = F, text="ID   Place
1     A
1     B
1     C
1     D
1     H
1     J
2     A
2     B
2     F
2     J
2     D
3     A
3     E
3     C
3     T
4     D
4     E
5     A
5     E
5     U
6     A
6     B
6     C
6     E
6     F")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` option is pasting the rows together in each dataset and get a logical index with `%in%` and negate `!` it to subset the rows of the original dataset ('df1')

```
df1[!do.call(paste, df1) %in% do.call(paste, rmdat),]
#    ID Place
#2   1     B
#3   1     C
#4   1     D
#5   1     H
#6   1     J
#7   2     A
#9   2     F
#10  2     J
#11  2     D
#12  3     A
#13  3     E
#15  3     T
#17  4     E
#18  5     A
#20  5     U
#21  6     A
#22  6     B
#23  6     C
#25  6     F
```

---

Or this can be done with `Reduce/Map/%in%/&` combination.

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, Map(`%in%`, df1, rmdat)),]
```